# Ajax to refresh partial not working in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show the user articles info in homepage, user click the `My Articles` link, then will show the info, doesn't need to refresh whole page:

for `ArticlesController`:

```
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @articles = @user.articles.page params[:page]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

`index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'index/my_articles' %>
```

partial view `_my_articles.html.erb`:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="my_articles">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <% @user.articles.each do |article| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= link_to article.title, user_article_path(@user, article) %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`index.js.erb`:

```
 $("#my_articles").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index/my_articles').html_safe %>");
```

nothing shows when I click the link, but the partial rendered according to rails log:

```
Started GET "/users/55daf9df57d2fa0a9c000006/articles" for ::1 at 2015-08-30 00:22:20 +0800
Processing by ArticlesController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"55daf9df57d2fa0a9c000006"}
  Rendered index/_my_articles.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered articles/index.js.erb (6.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 21.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am not familiar with ajax and JS, hope someone can help me, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try to remove `.html_safe`... and try.

Comment: @ArupRakshit thanks for your reply, but still doesn't work

Comment: @pangpang: What happens if you just do `$("#my_articles").html("");`?

Comment: @fylooi nothing happened, same as before

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `index/my_articles` is rendered in `index.html.erb`, which makes it present on first load. If this works, subsequent loads will have problems with multiple elements with the same ID, but that's besides the point of this question.

Comment: @pangpang: Load the page, and enter `$("#my_articles").html("");` into the console. What happens?

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are right, you are great!

Comment: @fylooi Thanks for your help, I set the "#my_articles" to wrong position

Comment: @fylooi If the first call comes as a JS, then the dom will not be there.. And that's what happening.. a single request will serve  either html or js file, as per the request type, but not the both. There things got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Add :remote=> true and put the end tag after the li tag.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="my_articles">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <% @user.articles.each do |article| %>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <%= link_to article.title, user_article_path(@user, article), :remote => true %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

In the index.js.erb edit to

```
$("#my_articles").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_articles').html_safe %>");
```